# Pass a js variable to a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on some links and I can't get it to work!
I would know how it works with php but I suck in js :P

So I use fancybox for some simple forms. But I need to pass the current url of document to that page, so we know where the one who filled the form in comes from! Every url is build like

example.com/city

So I need that city, so I can pass it to the iFrame, otherwise I need to make a page for each city...

```
<a class="button fancybox.iframe" id="offerte" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="offerte.php?page=city">Offerte aanvragen <span>»</span></a>
```

Something like this works, but I can't get in the href the right way!

```
document.write(document.URL);
```

How can I get the page link and pass it in the href??

Comment: you use can `window.location.href` to get current url and redirect to some new url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `location.href` property. If don't need domain and protocol there you can use `location.pathname`.

Read more about [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object at MDN.

You mentioned that you used jQuery in your tags, so w/ jQuery you can do this in that way:

```
$( '#offerte' ).attr( 'href', location.pathname );
```

and if you need to pass it as argument try this:

```
$( '#offerte' ).attr( 'href', 'offerte.php?page=' + location.pathname );
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I know how to get the url, but I can't get it in the href

Comment: I want to pass the value of the url to a php script like: offerte.php?page=example.com/city.html

Comment: Thanks man, that is what I was looking for, I forgot the quotes.. that's why it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

use window.location
more information here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
document.getElementById("offerte").setAttribute("href",location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

Assumption url: example.com/city --> example.com/paris

```
var u=window.location.href;
var city=u.substring(u.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
document.getElementById("offerte").setAttribute("href","offerte.php?page="+city);
```